# Upgraded to 2.4.1 now "out of Memory" on admin Order Grid

Tags: admin, magento2.4, memory

I upgraded to 2.4.1 from 2.3.6 and now cannot load the admin orders grid
Everything else seems OK, including things that are far more memory intensive, as far as I know, than the orders grid.

Currently running on php7.3.23 and the php memory limit is 2G

This is not a big site and I had done some test runs, but of course the test runs were done after taking personal information and orders out, for data protection reasons. So 10 test orders instead of 2500 live orders. But 2500 orders is not a massive amount either!

I don't even know where to start on this, hoping someone's seen this before?

I exported and imported the orders to one of the clone test sites, and there it instantly shows, no issues. I don't know where to look, there's nearly no difference in modules and they are on the same server, same environment etc.

The out of memory seems to be a bit random but mostly happens on Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php

```
[06-Nov-2020 08:10:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory in vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 202

[06-Nov-2020 08:35:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory  in vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.
php on line 295

[06-Nov-2020 09:19:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory  in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
on line 121

[06-Nov-2020 10:14:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory in vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php on
line 190
```

Comment: Have you tried with memory 8G or above?

Comment: i'm afraid that is not an option in this case @SaphalJha - but I also note that Magento notes 2G is a recommended size for normal operations and my site is tiny. 
I exported/imported all the sales tables to the clone site and there it works instantly, no memory needed

Comment: I removed and reverted modules and that seems to have fixed that problem, but it also looks as if I have this problem at the same time : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320037/magento-2-4-httpd-memory-leak-allowed-memory-size-of-792723456-bytes-exhausted